# Insert into syntax in Hive

Tags: hive

I have a non empty `table A` and want to append this, with data from `table B` (both have same #columns and data types).

Can I use normal Teradata sql insert syntax like

```
insert into table A 
select * from table B;
```

Should I make the `table A` immutable while creating ?

Comment: yes the syntax you showed works in Hive.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries

Comment: What do you mean "while creating"?

Answer (score 0):

if the sequence of column, data type and column is same in both the tables then you can use the syntax 
insert into table A select * from B;

and if the sequence is not same then you have to select each column from the B in the same sequence as table A.